# URL Variable to Jquery

Tags: ajax

On add_schedule.php I have created variable to pass to javascript:

```
var schedule_id = '<?php echo $schedule_id; ?>';
```

I'm like to add variable to URL, on common.js but i not have success:

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
runtimes : 'html5,html4',
url : 'upload.php?schedule_id='+ schedule_id,
max_file_size : '2mb',
unique_names : true
});
```

Any help to solve?

Comment: Is `schedule_id` showing up in the **view source** correctly?

Comment: yes, is showing up correctly :-)

Comment: Is `schedule_id` undefined  in JS code?

Comment: please define 'but i not have success'

Comment: Variable is not passed on url